# The Bash command :(){ :|:& };: will spawn processes to kernel death. Can you explain the syntax?

Tags: linux, bash

I looked at [this page](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/58/jaromils-forkbomb-do-not-use) and can't understand how this works.

This command "exponentially spawns subprocesses until your box locks up".

But why? What I understand less are the colons.

`user@host$ :(){ :|:& };:`

Comment: I'm sure this is an exact duplicate, but I can't find the original question right now.

Comment: I've had varying effects when trying this. Depending (I believe) on the configured upper limit for the number of processes and the CPU power, it caused barely a bump on some systems while completely freezing others.

Comment: @SpoonMeiser perhaps this is it?: http://askubuntu.com/questions/159491/why-did-the-command-make-my-system-lag-so-badly-i-had-to-reboot

Comment: https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=%3A%28%29%7B+%3A+%7C+%3A%26+%7D%3B+%3A

Answer (score 67, accepted):

That defines a function called  `:` which calls itself twice (Code: `: | :`). It does that in the background (`&`). After the `;` the function definition is done and the function `:` gets started.

So every instance of : starts two new : and so on... Like a binary tree of processes...

Written in plain C that is:

```
fork();
fork();
```

Comment: Closer C version: `while (fork() == 0 || fork() == 0);`

Answer (score 85):

```
:(){ :|:& };:
```

..defines a function named `:`, which spawns itself (twice, one pipes into the other), and backgrounds itself.

With line breaks:

```
:()
{
    :|:&
};
:
```

Renaming the `:` function to `forkbomb`:

```
forkbomb()
{
    forkbomb | forkbomb &
};
forkbomb
```

You can prevent such attacks by using `ulimit` to limit the number of processes-per-user:

```
$ ulimit -u 50
$ :(){ :|:& };:
-bash: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
$
```

More permanently, you can use `/etc/security/limits.conf` (on Debian and others, at least), for example:

```
* hard nproc 50
```

Of course that means you can only run 50 processes, you may want to increase this depending on what the machine is doing!

Comment: Upvoted - giving the : function a clearer name is exactly how I would have unobfuscated the code.

Comment: Why the pipe `|`? Golfing (`&&` could be used?) or is there a function?

Comment: @CiroSantilli: `&&` runs the commands sequentially.  `|` runs both simultaneously, with standard file handles redirected to a pipe.

Comment: Wouldn't recursebomb have the same effect?  recursebomb () { recursebomb }; recursebomb

Comment: @mpersico Your example is just an infinite loop, not a fork bomb.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the above answers, the behavior of pipe `|` is to create two processes at once and connect them with `pipe`(pipe is implemented by the operating system itself), so when we use pipe, each parent processes spawn two other processes, which leads to utilization of system resource exponentially so that resource is used up faster. 
 Also `&` is used to background the process and in this case prompts returns immediately so that the next call executes even faster.
[image: Exponential growth]
**Conclusion** :
`|`: To use system resource faster( with exponential growth)
`&`: background the process to get process started faster

Answer (score 0):

This defines a function called `:` (`:()`). Inside the function (`{...}`), there's a `:|:&` which is like this:

- `:` calls this `:` function again.
- `|` signifies piping the output to a command.
- `:` after `|` means pipe to the function `:`.
- `&`, in this case, means run the preceding in the background.

Then there's a `;` that is known as a command separator.

Finally, the `:` starts this "chain reaction", activating the [fork bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb).

The C equivalent would be:

```c
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
    fork();
    fork();
}
```