# How does this combined command :() { :|:& }; : work? (CAUTION: don't try, cause system halted)

Tags: linux, bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does this bash fork bomb work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991142/how-does-this-bash-fork-bomb-work)

Today one of my friend told me a funny thing, that this such command cause system halted:

```
:() { :|:& }; :
```

But, I just don't understand how does this command work and cause such a disaster.
Any one comes up with this thing?

Thanks,

Xi

Comment: Google forkbomb, this is not an original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short,

```
:() { :|:& }; :
|     |       ` Invoke the function
|     ` Run itself twice, once in a subshell, once for each invocation
` Create a new function called :
```

Which basically means that for each call of `:`, two instances of `:` are created, each of which create two more, etc.

The correct solution is sane ulimits.