# What does this bash script do?

Tags: bash

What does this line of bash do?

```
:(){ :|:& };:
```

My guess it's something nasty which is why I haven’t tried running it to see. Could someone explain with a dissection of the code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does this bash fork bomb work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991142/how-does-this-bash-fork-bomb-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First it creates a function named ":" (colon):

```
:(){ :|:& }
```

...then it runs it (semicolon separates the commands)

```
; :
```

The function

```
:() {  # Declaration
:|:&   # Runs "colon", pipes it to "colon", run in the background (&)
       # creating a loop
}      # Function end
```

Answer (score 4):

It is the classic [fork bomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb):

> a fork bomb is a denial-of-service attack whereby a process continually replicates itself to deplete available system resources

Comment: Thanks, I wish I had read your comment before running it locally in my cywgin *facepalm*