# Why is whitespace sometimes needed around metacharacters?

Tags: bash, shell, syntax, syntax-error

A few months ago I tattooed a [fork bomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb) on my arm, and I skipped the whitespaces, because I think it looks nicer without them. But to my dismay, **sometimes** (not always) when I run it in a shell it doesn't start a fork bomb, but it just gives a syntax error.

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `{:'
```

Yesterday it happened when I tried to run it in a friend's [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) shell, and then I added the whitespace and it suddenly worked, `:(){ :|:& };:` instead of `:(){:|:&};:`

Does the whitespace matter; have I tattooed a syntax error on my arm?!

It seems to always work in [zsh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell), but not in Bash.

[A related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991142/how-does-this-bash-fork-bomb-work) does not explain anything about the whitespaces, which really is my question; **Why is the whitespace needed for Bash to be able to parse it correctly?**

Comment: I posted the same question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42348/shell-function-definitionwhy-is-there-a-space-after-the-opening-brace) (excluding the tattoo part).

Comment: Also, the colon (:) can't be used as a function name (see: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01_01) ... FreeBSD's /bin/sh even gives an error on this ...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: I'm not sure how that's relevant. This questions is about Bash.

Answer (score 272, accepted):

There is a list of characters that separate tokens in BASH. These characters are called *metacharacters* and they are `|`, `&`, `;`, `(`, `)`, `<`, `>`, **space** and **tab**. On the other hand, curly braces (`{` and `}`) are just ordinary characters that make up words.

Omitting the second space before `}` will do, since `&` is a metacharacter. Therefore, your tattoo should have at least one space character.

```
:(){ :|:&};:
```

Comment: Easy solution: move the first part of the taoo towards the left and transplant skin between the two parts.

Comment: I liked the term, `on the other hand`... pun intended? ;) :D (Sorry, for off the topic comment.)

Comment: But this is different for zsh? In what way is zsh different?

Comment: Good explanation, except that `{` and `}` are _shell keywords_ in this context. Only if they're not recognized as such - due to lack of surrounding spaces/metacharacters - are they treated as a literal part of the word they become a part of.
(And then there's brace expansion, which happens in a different context.)

Comment: @mklement0 Thank you, good point, `{` and `}` are single character keywords. There is little use in combining them with other characters to form longer words since braces in names are not allowed. Yet you need to separate them with a delimiter.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov Braces are allowed in command names (including functions: `{foo} () { echo hello; }`. "Name", as defined in by `bash` as "a word  consisting  only  of  alphanumeric characters and underscores, and beginning with an alphabetic
              character or an underscore", applies only to variable names.

Answer (score 85):

Just tattoo a

```
#!/bin/zsh
```

shebang above it and you'll be fine.

Comment: If we're picky, the shebang would not work at all, as the shell, hopefully zsh, is in interactive mode, as evidenced by the prompt...

Answer (score 50):

Braces are more like odd keywords than special symbols, and do need spaces. This is different to parentheses, for example. Compare:

```
(ls)
```

which works, and:

```
{ls}
```

which looks for a command named `{ls}`. To work, it has to be:

```
{ ls; }
```

The semicolon stops the closing brace being taken as a parameter to `ls`.

All you have to do is tell people that you are using a proportional-font with a rather narrow space character.

Comment: @Alfe no, this is not a compound statement.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov - it's a very sneaky trick, using a completely different meaning of braces. It expands the comma-separated list of values, which in this case is just the `ls`.

Comment: I was just being silly.  Don't take my last comment too earnest ;-)

Comment: But … boy … you are going to have the tattoo for the rest of your life!  You marked yourself as a nerd for all time!  And _then_ you couldn't even get it right before having it stitched?  That's two steps beyond being nerdy I guess ;-)  No offense, pal, I'm just wondering.

Comment: @Alfe I tried it before I tattooed it, but I tried it in my zsh, I thought it had the same parsing as bash. Foolish of me, but I'll just tell people that it's zsh. :)

Comment: @spydon Or you tell them that you left out the space on purpose so that people copying the command from your tattoo won’t accidentally run it and crash their machine ;)

Comment: @Alfe He is in Australia: reality is upside down there ;-) But, more seriously, can the original then be fixed with a comma before the "}", instead of needing a space after "{"? Maybe the tattoo artist could slip it in?  (Or does your comma example just work for `ls`?)

Comment: No, that opening brace is interpreted as a function block opener because of the part before it, and no matter whether there's a comma in the block or not.

Comment: Hey, if it's valid in zsh, why not just add #!/bin/zsh right above it (or before it)?  It's good practice to specify the shell first, anyhow.

Answer (score 41):

Although not easily visible in the tatoo font, there's actually a Byte-Order Mark (BOM) between the brace and the colon (you may have been sufficiently intoxicated when you got the tatoo that you didn't notice it, but it's really there). This leaves three obvious possibilities:

1. You've failed to type in the BOM when you transcribed the code. The result is an obvious application of GIGO. The shell simply doesn't recognize a BOM that isn't present in your failed transcription.
2. Your shell is too old. It doesn't recognize Unicode characters, so the BOM (and probably all other Unicode characters) is being ignored completely, even though a BOM anywhere but the beginning of a file is supposed to be treated as a zero-width, non-breaking space.
3. Your shell is too new. Use of a BOM as a ZWNBS is deprecated, and the authors have implemented a future version of Unicode in which this usage is no longer allowed.

Answer (score 40):

> and then I added the whitespace and it suddenly worked ...

It's because of how the shell parses.  You need a space after the function definition begins, i.e. after the `{`.

```
foo() { echo hey& }
foo() { echo hey&}
foo(){ echo hey&}
```

are valid.  On the other hand,

```
foo() {echo hey&}
```

isn't.

---

You actually need a tatoo like this:

[image]

---

From the [source](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/braces.c):

```c
  /* We ignore an open brace surrounded by whitespace, and also
     an open brace followed immediately by a close brace preceded
     by whitespace.  */
```

Omitting a space after the `{` causes the `{echo` to be interpreted as a single token.

---

An equivalent form of

```
:(){ :|:& };:
```

would be

```
:(){
:|:& };:
```

Note that there is no space after `{` in the alternate version, but a line-break causes the shell to recognize `{` as a token.

Comment: "Omitting a space after the { causes the {echo to be interpreted as a single token." -- so does the parser believe it has encountered a command called `{echo` before it has reached a required opening brace?

Comment: LOL. That picture, happens to be my neck :)