# Shortest way to remove /boot/ after a random amount of time

Tags: bash, sh, zsh

As the title says, what is the shortest way to remove the /boot folder after a random amount of time in Bash (or Zsh)?

The purpose of this is a tattoo, with similar length of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21186724/why-is-whitespace-sometimes-needed-around-metacharacters) one, which is 19 characters long (or 20 with correct syntax) and 11 without the prompt.

Old tattoo: `life:~# :(){:|:&};:`

I've tried this so far, which is too many characters (42 without prompt):

```
life:~# if [ $RANDOM = 1 ]; then; rm -r /boot; fi
```

Comment: The `[ $RANDOM = 1 ]` performs only a single test.  That's only a 1 in 32767 chance of removing `/boot`. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little shorter...

```
sleep $RANDOM;rm -r /boot
```

To be honest, the significance of removing boot is lost on me. A box can keep running without it.  How about `kill -9 1` instead?

Comment: The box will keep running, but you better not halt it. `#kill -9 1` might be his next tattoo ;)

Comment: As you need to restart the box as an effect of the other tattoo you wont be able to start it again. :)

Answer (score 1):

The `if` can conveniently be replaced with a short-circuit.

```
[ $RANDOM = 1 ] && rm -r /boot
```

This still performs only a single shot with a fairly low probability of actually doing anything.

You could somewhat more obscurely use arithmetic context, which evaluates to false (1) if the value of the calculation is zero.

```
(($RANDOM)) || rm -r /boot
```

Running this in a tight loop with `while` is obviously longer, and does not wait for very long before I get a zero (typically less than a second); you could add a `sleep` to delay it but this is already pretty long.

```
while (($RANDOM)) || { rm -r /boot; false; }; do : ; done
```

The pesky `false` and the braces is to get the loop to exit when the random number "finally" reaches zero.

Comment: I guess the last one might be possible to do recursively to get down the number of characters a bit.