# :(){ :|:& };: Forkbomb?

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The following bash command will spawn processes to kernel death. Can you explain the syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515844/the-following-bash-command-will-spawn-processes-to-kernel-death-can-you-explain)

```
:(){ :|:& };:
```

running this fork() unlimited .. Can one please explain this bash script ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You define a function called `:`. Inside this function you call this function twice (`:|:`) and then you send that process to the background (`&`). Then you finally call it at the end.

Because of the recursive nature, you'll keep forking. Since there is no base case, the recursion will never end.