# Can colon be used as identifier?

Tags: linux, bash

I saw a code in [The Bash command :(){ :|:& };: will spawn processes to kernel death. Can you explain the syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515844/the-following-bash-command-will-spawn-processes-to-kernel-death-can-you-explain) as follows

```
user@host$ :(){ :|:& };:
```

Here colon used as identifier for function name.
Can colon be used as identifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can.

```
$ :()
> {
> echo "hello from : :)"
> }
$ :
hello from : :)
```

Comment: Yep, it is working. Can you have any url saying colon can be used as identifier?

Comment: There are no such URL (I'm aware of), but please take a look at the discussion: http://old.nabble.com/Document-what's-allowed-in-function-names-td31361546.html ; it may be interesting for you.

Comment: I think you can leave it here :) Thank you, it's pleasant to read, but it is of course not true. John Skeet, Darin Dimitrov, Balus — they are the people who are really great.

Comment: But you got these points within 14 days. How did you get? can you give me your email? if you ready, send to my email the same user id in gmail.

Comment: There is no secret here. I just answer the questions :)

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-identifier-11):

> name
>
> A word consisting solely of letters, numbers, and underscores, and beginning with a letter or underscore. Names are used as shell variable and function names. Also referred to as an identifier.

No, the colon is not valid in function names. So either the bomb doesn't work in bash, or the documentation is failing.

I shortly thought that the colon might refer to the [built-in operator](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-g_t_003a-107), but I don't see how that could get the expected semantics.

Comment: There is an example in that page.
" 
$ ulimit -u 50
$ :(){ :|:& };:
-bash: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
 "
It means he used colon as function name, right?

Comment: `:(){ echo "CIXON" }; :` ran `echo "CIXON"` and the output is `CIXON`. It does work.

Comment: @user11462042 you forgot a semicolon in your command. `:(){ echo "CIXON"; }; :` works indeed.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation seems to be inconsistent. You can define and call a function containing colons and Google even suggests this for packages in their [style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shell.xml?showone=Function_Names#Function_Names).

Though I noticed you can not export nor unset these functions.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

foo:bar() {
  echo "foo:bar called"
}

foo:bar

export -f foo:bar

unset foo:bar
```

The `export` won't complain but if you call another bash script afterwards `foo:bar` is not available.

The unset will even trigger an error:

```
/foo/bar: line 11: unset: `foo:bar': not a valid identifier
```

---

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```